# Loop through All Objects of a Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have some class called `loopObject` and I initialize every object through something like `var apple = new loopObject();`  Is there anyway to loop through all objects of a class so that some function can be performed with each object as a parameter?  If there isn't a direct method, is there a way to place each new object into an array upon initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an array that contains every instance, like this:

```
function LoopObject() {
    LoopObject.all.push(this);
}
LoopObject.all = [];
```

However, it will leak memory - your instances will never go out of scope.

Comment: Wouldn't reading the all array from the bottom and removing each item after use kill the instance and save memory?

Comment: @faraz: If you know when to kill it, yes.  However, every time you call `new LoopObject()` and don't kill it, you'll leak.  Remember to kill inside a `finally` block.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined on the line `LoopObject.all.push(this);`

Comment: @faraz: You forgot `LoopObject.all = [];` (Or you deleted or re-assigned it elsewhere)

Comment: The empty square brackets causes a token error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]"

Comment: @faraz: `[]` is valid syntax for an array in all browsers.  Please show me your exact code.  Or, change it to `LoopObject.all = new Array();`

Answer (score 1):

```
function loopObject(){
 this.name = 'test'
};
var list = [], x = new loopObject, y = new loopObject;

list.push(x)
list.push(y)

for ( var i = list.length; i--; ) {
    alert( list[i].name )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var allObjects [] = new Array();
function loopObject() {
    ...
    allObjects.push(this);
}
```

Then one can loop through all elements of `allObjects` as necessary using `allObjects.length`.

Comment: This is exactly what I answered, except with `allObjects` as a  global.